# Using PDOStatement::bindValue in MSSQL "Contains"

Tags: php, symfony, pdo

I'd like to bind values to a MSSQL "Contains" clause. The result should look as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM [aTable] WHERE CONTAINS(name, '"miller*")
```

I tried the following way:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM [aTable] WHERE CONTAINS(name, '":name*"')";
```

and later on... (is a symfony2 project)

```
$stmt = $em->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue('name', 'miller');
```

but unfortunately it doesn't work. Error:

```
pdo invalid parameter number parameter was not defined
```

It there a way to achieve this? Thank you!!

**UPDATE:**
I ended up with the following. I prepare the CONTAINS argument before and then bind it to the parameter:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM [aTable] WHERE CONTAINS(name, :values)";
$contains_args_string = '"Mil*" AND "Joh*"';
$stmt = $em->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':values', $contains_args_string, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: have you tried `CONTAINS(name, :name + '*');` ?

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work. This leads to mssql incorrect syntax error.